# CSS - перемещение блока с помощью margin и padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, отступы

У меня есть некая картинка который я хочу перемещать вправо, я не очень понимаю что использовать `margin-left` или `paddgin-left`? я понимаю что разница между ними это внешние и внутренние отступы но в моем случаи они делают тоже самое, можете посмотреть на пример моего сайта https://ibb.co/XZdQMCC (за ранее извиняюсь за мелкий шрифт) подскажите пожалуйста что лучше всего использовать `margin` или `padding`?

Comment: В данном случае без разницы. В другом, если бы были соседние блоки, пришлось бы отталкиваться от контекста.

Comment: добавь пример разметки и стилей непосредственно в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

`margin` или `padding` - это внешние и внутренние отступы.

Если вам нужно отпозиционировать ваш элемент относительно других **внешних элементов** всегда в первую очередь используйте `margin`, а если, в зависимости от окружающего контекста, использование `margin` затруднительно, то в крайнем случае используйте `padding`.

Если вам нужно отпозиционировать несколько **дочерних элементов** относительно своего **родительского элемента**, то используйте `padding` у родительского элемента.